# Can a player change perspective after entering the center?

Tags: and-then-we-held-hands

In the game [...and then we held hands](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/153999/and-then-we-held-hands), after the first player enters the center, is he allowed to change perspective (change which side of the cards can be used)?

Normally when the player ends his turn in the middle of the board, he is allowed to choose if he is going to change perspective. However, the rules says:

> If at the end of a turn the player’s token is located on a node on the middle line (i.e., in neither half of the board), the player may choose whether to change perspective or not, deciding whether to do this without looking at the covered halves of the emotion cards.

Is the center considered a node on the middle? And so, after the first player enters the center, can he change the visible side of the cards in order to help the other player?

Thank you.

Comment: The game is called ...and then we held hands

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that was the game name! I've added a tag for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve sent an e-mail to Ludicreations and this is what they´ve replied:

"yes, you are allowed to change perspective after entering the center."